# Public Ip address of puppet agent

Tags: puppet

I am using Puppet for automation purpose. How can I get public IP address of agent machine connected to puppetserver. I want to use that IP address in my puppet manifest file.

Comment: The Puppet agent provides a set of [*facts*](https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/6.4/lang_facts_and_builtin_vars.html) about itself and its host as part of each catalog request.  These are available to the catalog builder as top-scope variables, and also via the top-scope `$facts` hash.  They include information about network interfaces and, in particular, IP addresses.

Comment: Perhaps this could be converted to an answer @JohnBollinger and resolved? Just trying to do some cleaning up in here!

Comment: Ok, @AlexHarvey, there you go.

Answer (score 1):

The Puppet agent provides a set of [facts](https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/6.4/lang_facts_and_builtin_vars.html) about itself and its host as part of each catalog request. These are available to the catalog builder as top-scope variables, and also via the top-scope `$facts` hash. They include information about network interfaces and, in particular, IP addresses.

Do note, however, that machines typically have multiple IP addresses (including local addresses), some even have multiple *routable* addresses, and some must be referred to by different addresses in one network location than they are in others.  Thus, the "public IP address" of a machine is not necessarily well- or uniquely defined.  Facter does take a guess as to a single IP address for machines with IP networking, but you should not rely on that without an awareness of these issues.